# Vuetify .input-group__details change min-height impossible

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm not an CSS Expert but until now I've not seen any "problem" like this.

So, I am using Vuetify and I added a  for my search form..

Now that component is creating:

```
<div input-group input-group--prepend-icon input-group--text-field primary--text>
  <label for="search"></label>
  <div class="input-group__input"></div>
  <div class="input-group__details"></div>
  <div class="input-group__messages"></div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is that class .input-group__messages has a min-height and I want it to have 1px or not show at this case, but I can't manage to edit that from my component... there is the way to go to root style but I don't want to do that I want to learn or to know what's the problem what am I missing.

Looking forward for a reply from someone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `vue-loader` version [12.2+](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v12.2.0) and use [Deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Using CSS (also **works** with `stylus` but your IDE might throw syntax errors):

```
>>> .input-group__messages {
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

Or SCSS:

```
/deep/ .input-group__messages {
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985784/1981247) for explanations, and other possible solutions if the above did not work.

Comment: thnx bro, I've never heard of deep actually I never used it until now, but now my problem is fixed and I learned something new :) I appreciate your help