# Vuetify - CSS not working (taking effect) inside component

Tags: vuetify.js

**Case 1**
We are trying to apply custom a style to a rendered vuetify element:

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name" />
</template>

<style scoped>
  .input-group__input {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

But there are no changes.

---

**Case 2**  
We are trying to style elements rendered by `v-html` (e.g. external html). For example, we try to apply custom width and height on the `img`, but it doesn't work:

```html
<template>
  <div v-html="customHTML"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    customHTML: `<img src="https://vuetifyjs.com/static/doc-images/carousel/planet.jpg">`;
  })
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
</style>
```

How to apply custom CSS to those elements?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805913/vuejs-vuetify-color-theme-not-working

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**NOTE**: Make sure to include styles as per [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#existing-applications)
Also in case of broken components make sure that your app is wrapped inside `v-app` tag:

```
<v-app> 
    <v-content>
    //..
    </v-content>
</v-app>
```

[Documentation says](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined):

> In order for your application to work properly, you must wrap it in a
>   `v-app` component.

---

## Solution

use `vue-loader`'s [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) `>>>` like so:

Case 1:

```
>>>.input-group__input {
    background: red;
}
```

Case 2:

```
>>>img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

So there is no need to remove `scoped` attribute from `<style>` tag.

Excerpt from [docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) with regards to pre-processors (for example if you are using `<style lang="scss" scoped>`):

> Some pre-processors, such as Sass, may not be able to parse `>>>` properly. In those cases you can use the `/deep/` combinator instead - it's an alias for `>>>` and works exactly the same.

**Note**: deep-selectors were [implemented in `v12.2.0`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v12.2.0)

### Explanation

In both cases CSS changes are not taking effect because elements you are trying to style are not part of your component, and thus don't have `data-v-xxxxxxx` attribute, which is used for styling elements in the current scope (component) when using `<style scoped>`.
When using `scoped` attribute we tell the vue to apply css only to elements with `data-v-xxxxxxx`, but **not nested** elements. Thus we need to explicitly use deep-selectors.

For example, in case `#1` rendered `<v-text-field>` will look like so:

```
// notice `data-v-61b4012e` here:
<div data-v-61b4012e class="input-group input-group--text-field primary--text">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="input-group__input"> // and notice no `data-v-61b4012e` here
        <input tabindex="0" aria-label="Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group__details"></div>
</div>
```

And in case `#2` rendered `v-html` looks like this:

```
<div data-v-61b4012e> // notice `data-v-61b4012e` here  
    // and no `data-v-61b4012e` on image
    <img src="https://vuetifyjs.com/static/doc-images/carousel/planet.jpg">
</div>
```

#### Still not working?

If you are trying to override some style (inline-style) and this solution did not work, you might want to [see more about CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728504/1981247).

---

**Bugs?**
It's possible that even if you target properly and use deep-selectors that style is not applied as you would expect. Check if there is coresponding data-v-xxxxxx property on one of the parent elements in rendered html, there might be cases (bugs) when it's not applied, so then there is no way to target it via scoped css. [One example was v-menu rendered by v-select](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5568), but probably possible to encounter other similar bugs in the future.

Comment: I've been searching for the deep selectors all along but when googling you can't find anything... Thank you so much, you just saved me a lot of time and stress :-)

Comment: I had trouble installing vuetify. Then, all the colors were black and white. I shrugged it off for a bit but i was bothered. Turned out it was as you say: wrap the app in <v-app>. The colors magically appeared. Thanks!

Comment: `v-app` worked for me. When add the router (with Vue Cli) it change my v-app for a div#app.

Comment: I love u bro, ive forgotten the <v-app> in my nested routes. Thanks for this post!

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't developed Vue for a while and forgot the `v-app` thing!

Comment: In my case I did add vuetify trough CLI method, but the CSS styles didn't work. So, I had to backward to the docs to copy the content of the vuetify.js's file from plugin folder and that have fixed my problem. This is the reference link https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install

Comment: ```.a::v-deep { .b { padding: 1px; } }```
Worked for me, but not /deep/ and other deep selectors