# How to override vuetify styles?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to override the vuetify style by class.

For example to change the background color of button from vuetify.

So, I create a button with class on it:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-btn class="some" color="success">Success</v-btn>
</div>

<style>
  .some {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

But the background-color red is override by vuetify.

How to solve this issue without using important and themes?

Here is example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-js-gpkj6k

Comment: Actually see this about CSS specificity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717264/styling-vuetify-selectors/51728504#51728504 I put a duplicate flag initially, but wrong question. In the former question it was only a part of the answer that led to the second question. So you can just target it with  `#app .some` for example. Of course use what is best for you once you learn these concepts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling Vuetify selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717264/styling-vuetify-selectors)

Answer (score 30):

With vue and scoped elements, you will meet the /deep/, >>>, ::v-deep selectors. Everything is explained [there](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors). So if you want to override a style deep, this means a style of a child of your root vuetify component you will need to use `::v-deep` selector along with `scoped` attribute.

This gives you:

```html
<style scoped>
  .parent-element >>> .vuetify-class {
    // values
  }
</style>
    
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .vuetify-class {
    ::v-deep other-class {
      // your custom css properties
    }
  }
</style>
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 25):

Having worked with Vuetify and it's various styling... eccentricities... I believe it's all boiled down to writing css that has more specificity than Vuetify.

It's never great practise to style element's directly (`img`), instead apply your own classes.

This way you could declare `.my-card.v-card` and win the specificity war, all the while keeping styles scoped (non scoped can the the devil to debug in vue files).

Some Vuetify style declarations use `!important`... so the only way I've found to override these are to also use `!important` on the override.
IMO terrible decision from Vuetify to have *any* `!important` styles.

It's also good to get your head around `>>>, /deep/, ::v-deep` as can provide a solution where styles are not filtering through.

Comment: Just introducing Vuetify into my project broke all kinds of styling, even when I have my styles loading after it in the pipeline.  Perhaps the single most frustrating one is the fact that `input`, `select`, and `button` ALL have no borders now. In a form-heavy app, adding classes to every one of these elements is time-consuming.  Even adding it to `<style>` tags didn't help. Very developer-unfriendly.

Comment: I also make a habit to have global override stylesheets, targeting vendor styling. So, _not_ in your component files, but within a separate stylesheet that you would import into `main.js`. That is... only if you want to override *all* vuetify input styling, for example. This way you avoid adding classes etc to the vuetify elements too.

Comment: Going through process of customizing vuetify components - ` win the specificity war` is a great way of describing it haha

Comment: @trpt4him, you can pump up the specificity of any SCSS rules by wrapping them in `body:not(#_){ ... code here }` (assuming your `<body>` element doesn't have `id="_"`). Obviously, you don't need to use `body` *per se* but it's a good practice to limit the assertion of `:not()` to as few elements as possible. If you want, it's a custom `!important` which doesn't cross the line of not being overrideable by inline styles (so it doesn't break JS styling) and, as you can see, it doesn't need to know any ancestor `id` or `class`.

Comment: Plus 1 just for the "... eccentricities ...". Made my day since it is so true

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov hahaha it's painfully true.. like... Why?! There's a whole load of ways to override styles without resorting to `!important` 

Comment: That decision was made by vuetify team. They use !important and calc a lot :)

Comment: @tao Thanks for the tip.  I'm struggling because I'm primarily a Python guy and having to `body:not()` things is violating multiple points of our Zen.  :)

Comment: I totally get it, but it's superior to `!important`. You only need to follow a simple rule: use only one element for `:not()` assertion (not all parents). It allows you to increase specificity of your rules without having to specify ancestor classes or ids. So `html:not(#_):not(#_) input` will override powerful selectors like: `#app input.form-control` or `#navbar input.search`, because it has specificity of `2×id + 1×element` vs `1×id + 1×class + 1×element`. The other option is to copy currently applying selectors and override them one by one with same specificity. Insane... ish.

Comment: @trpt4him do you have a solution to the no border problem. I can't even get  borders using my own classes. heeelp!!!!! :(

Comment: @4uroraskye any chance you could give an example of a separate style sheet and how you import it ?

Answer (score 5):

Try not scoping your styles for example:

```html
<body>
<img :src="userImg" alt="avatar">
</body>
```

This won't work

```
<style scoped>
.img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img img {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

And this will work

```html
<style>
    .img {
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-radius: 50% !important;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .img img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: This is fine, if you don't mind that your styles may bleed into other places.
I find it best when working with Vue, to always scope styles - there is usually another way round styling elements without resorting to unscoping styles.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround I have found is targeting the elements specifically in the custom CSS by giving the containing element an ID like below

```
<v-btn-toggle
 id="btnGroup"
 borderless
 dense
 group
 class="d-flex flex-column"
>
  <v-btn active-class="dnrSelected">
    <v-icon right class="mr-2">mdi-close</v-icon>
    <span>Do Not Recommend</span>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn active-class="rSelected">
    <v-icon right class="mr-1">mdi-check</v-icon>
    <span>Recommend</span>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn active-class="srSelected">
    <v-icon right class="mr-1">mdi-check-all</v-icon>
    <span>Strongly Recommend</span>
  </v-btn>
</v-btn-toggle>
```

And then using this `id` to specify target elements like below

```
#btnGroup .dnrSelected {
  background-color: #ef9a9a !important;
}
#recommendationBtnGroup .rSelected {
  background-color: #dcedc8 !important;
}
#recommendationBtnGroup .srSelected {
  background-color: #81c784 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with `Vuetify 3` you'll see a warning `::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use ::v-deep(<inner-selector>) instead` for `::v-deep` usage. The other methods didn't give my any single warning and didn't work.

The way to change the styling is, depending if you need to overwrite styling (add `!important;`), or simply append a new one (no need for `!important;`), is, with an example:

```css
:deep() {
  .v-field__outline__end {
    border-radius: 25px!important;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is/will be an issue you're having, but I was stuck on it for a long time.

If you use scoped styling (which you should), you'll have to use the deep selector `>>>` to target classes of child components. I could never get the deep selector to work with SASS though, so you'll have to either forgo using SASS or use both.

```html
<style scoped>
.parent-element >>> .vuetify-class {
  // values
}
</style>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  // SASS styling
</style>
```

You can read about the deep selector here:
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way was to add my custom-reset.css file where I have put my fixes.
For example if you load vuetify css like this:

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

You can import your custom-reset.css file after that line, as a result you imports will look line this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import '<your_path>/custom-reset.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
```

I had problems, vuetify styles broke AdminLte 2 styling. In my case, custom-reset.css file can look like this:

```
.row {
    display: block;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.row > .col, .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, 
.col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, 
.col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, 
.col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, 
.col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-auto, 
.col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, 
.col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, 
.col-md-12, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, 
.col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, 
.col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, 
.col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, 
.col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-auto {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist; /* -webkit-appearance: none;  */
}
.v-application--wrap {
    min-height: auto;
}
```

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

[image: htl div]

In Vue 3 And Vuetify 3:

```
<div class="v-responsive v-img" style="width: 85vw;">
```

```
div:deep(.v-img) {
  overflow: visible;
}
```