# Vuetify - Overriding template slots with scoped CSS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I got some problems with overriding the CSS on slots inside an autocomplete.
I read this thread and tried multiple solutions, but none work that are feasible (since they globally change the style for vuetify components):
[How to override vuetify styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310060/how-to-override-vuetify-styles)

How would I override the autocomplete styles? E.g right now my problem is that I'm adding an append-slot with a button inside the search field, but the padding of the text field pushes it too much to the left & no padding is applied on the bottom.

[image]

Some things I tried:
Creating a parent element with an ID and then manually trying to create a class for it.

Example:

```
#handlesearch > div > div > div.v-input__slot > div.v-select__slot > div {
  margin-top: 4px !important;
}


     <template id="handlesearch" slot="append">
       <v-btn
      >Sök</v-btn
     >
   </template>
```

Comment: I was facing the same problem, overriding slots or any other component css is not generally possible in the scoped css. I ended up writing global css for that specific component based on parent selector (so it applied only on that one)

Comment: I guess that's a reasonable solution since it indeed does solve my problem even if it's not optimal. However, this is more of a Vuetify inherent problem so I'll accept it:) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your html, you'll notice that adding ID on `<template>` is not working. If you move your `id="handlesearch"` to actual html element inside your slot, which is in this case `v-btn`.

```
<template slot="append">
    <v-btn id="handlesearch">Sök</v-btn>
</template>
```

with next scoped style

```
<style scoped>
    #handlesearch {
      background: red;
    }
</style>
```

Produces next result:

[image: Visual example]

If I move `id="handlesearch"` to  `<template>` as `<template id="handlesearch">` style will not be applied since in my DOM there is no HTML element with that id.

### Solution

Move your ID to actual element inside your slot, and add scoped style according to that.