# Styling vuetify v-data-table

Tags: css, vuetify.js

Between each not-last-child row of a v-data-table a line is being printed by default. I would like to modify the css to change that line, e.g. remove it. Originally, in the developer console the css regarding the border-bottom looks as follows.

```
.theme--light.v-table tbody tr:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
```

I have assigned the data-table an additional class "mytable":

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1 mytable">
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

And with css I am trying to modify the table

```
.mytable table tr {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Although the background-color is changed to lightgoldenrodyellow the border-bottom is still printed. In the developer console the directive to remove the border-bottom is stroken through. The background-color is not. Which selector do I have to use to change as well the border-bottom? Using the same css as used by the theme originally doesn't work either.

Comment: Probably the ones you mentioned are used `.mytable .v-table tbody tr:not(:last-child)` (and .theme--light if you want it to remove specifically for the light theme I guess)?

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: It [works](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXapWq), unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: I agree. It does work in your example. For some reason it doesn't work in my app (which I cannot post/publish). Will have to continue my search. Thank you for your help! If I find the cause I'll publish it here.

Comment: I suspect it's because you are using scoped styles in your app. To deal with that, you might want to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985784/1981247

Answer (score 5):

> Which selector do I have to use to change the border-bottom?

Use your custom class and the one used by vuetify

```
.mytable .v-table tbody tr:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Additionally you can add `.theme--light` if you want to style the light theme specifically.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXapWq)

---

More about styling vuetify components:

[CSS not working (taking effect) inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985784/1981247)
[Styling Vuetify selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728504/1981247)

Comment: @iamwhitebox 
Could you be more specific? It appears that this answer might be out of date, and that some elements might have been changed in vuetify over the years. Also it's possible that you were using scoped styles, and missing the selectors? You can find more info in the linked `CSS not working (taking effect) inside component` thread.

Comment: It's crazy dumb stuff like this that forced me to revert to using regular HTML tables instead of Vuetify's "special" tables. They're so hard to style properly without resorting to deep selecting Vuetify classes or doing stuff like this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `VueJS 2.x`. the following way of selection worked for me well.

```css
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.table-header /deep/ {
  thead {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Vuetify version 2.3.21. After trying a lot of things, I managed to remove the lines by changing `td`. Changing `tr` did not remove the lines, but you can change it to color the row, for example.

I also had to use `!important`. I added this to my page's CSS:

```
.v-data-table td {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

This modification works with `<v-simple-table>` as well.

Comment: This worked for me, removed border in data rows

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
.v-data-table tbody tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12) !important; }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important`, it can solve your problem.
If it does not work try restarting your server.

```
.mytable table tr {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    border-bottom: none !important;
 }
```