# Override vuetify without !important

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to apply custom CSS and override some default Vuetify colors. For example, success button can be easily overridden:

```
.success-button {
  background-color: $sb--color-success !important;
}
```

But is there a way to do the same without using `!important`? I tried both:

```
body .success-button {
    background-color: $sb--color-success;
}

button .success-button {
  background-color: $sb--color-success;
}
```

How to do it without `!important`?

Comment: Vuetify uses colors with `!important` by default, you need `!important` to override other important rules

Comment: Your question is too broad. What are you trying to do? Replace the default color (theme)? Or you can use different values in `.styl`...  Or learn more about specificity if specificity is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728504/1981247 These questions have likely been answered (or is explained in the docs), but impossible to know what do you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along this lines

```
// src/index.js

// Libraries
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

    // Helpers
    import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
      theme: {
        primary: colors.red.darken1, // #E53935
        secondary: colors.red.lighten4, // #FFCDD2
        accent: colors.indigo.base // #3F51B5
      }
    })
```

Or something like this

```
 <h1 class="subheading grey--text">DASHBOARD</h1>
```

Comment: is 'index.js' the same as 'main.js'? As long as I don't have index.js file at all.

Comment: Could be. Where did u import vuetify?

Comment: inside this main.js. Thank you, I'll try your solution

Comment: @Desiigner If solution helped you you should accept provided answer :)