# How to change error color of Vuetify component?

Tags: css, vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I'm trying to adjust the color of my error messages from my Combobox. I tried to overwrite the style I saw getting applied, but it just isn't sticking. I saw the normal way to apply styles in Vuetify is to add [color]--text to a component, but what would I need to do to set just the error style?

```
<style>
.error--text {
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    caret-color: rgb(2, 0, 0) !important;
}
</style>
```

EDIT: 
Here is a [reproduction](https://codepen.io/dicquack/pen/NmOqjQ) of the issue

Comment: What's wrong with your approach (except using global style, but easily solved by setting id/class or using scoped styles)? Can you reproduce on codepen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNEbOV)

Add arbitrary class to your component (e.g. `app-combobox`):

`<v-combobox class="app-combobox"`

Then style like so:

```
.app-combobox.error--text,
.app-combobox .error--text {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
  caret-color: rgb(2, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Vuetify uses `!important` as well so it seems that vuetify style has higher level of [specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717264/styling-vuetify-selectors/51728504#51728504), thus you need to add your own class and use it so that it has more.
It seems that `.app-combobox.error--text` is needed to color the input line, and `.app-combobox. error--text` (with space) to color child components i.e. text and icons.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Nuxt with Vuetify module. I just updated the error color in the nuxt.config.js, and all works fine for me.