# Problems adding custom CSS to Vuetify component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working with the Vuetify selector input component, `v-select`, and I want to custom style it. Since the component renders with only one `v-select` and no necessary children in the html, I turned to styling the component via inspecting in chrome and copying down the class there. For example, to change the font size of the active value, I used:

```
.v-select__selections {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

This worked fine, until I realized my styles in this manner did not work on *any* parts of the (normally hidden) navigation drawer. For example,

```
.v-menu__content {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Would not impact the styles in any way. Bizarrely enough, it was not simply my styles getting overwritten by Vuetify styles (!important had no effect) - it appeared that my CSS didn't reach the components at all. There was no trace of any of my written styles upon inspect. How?

I believe this is due to the active-based nature of the drawer-part of the selector component. Is there another way I should be addressing those kinds of elements in CSS? I wish I could provide a Jsfiddle, but (on the templates I've found), Vuetify renders completely differently. I'm using Vuetify 1.1.7.

My styles are included directly in the component .vue file, non scoped. Vuetify and vuetify styles are imported in main.js:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
```

File structure (Default structure from `vue init webpack -myProject`):

```
src/
    -main.js 
    -app.vue 
    -components/
        -problematicComponent.vue
index.html
```

Edit: I also tried using deep selectors, but the problem still remained with the hidden menu components:

```
>>>.v-menu__content {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Therefore the problem I have is different than the problem here:

> [Vuetify - CSS not working (taking effect) inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985783/vuetify-css-not-working-taking-effect-inside-component)

Comment: Is your CSS scoped?

Comment: No it is not. Interestingly enough, when I scoped the CSS, *none* of the styles worked. I'm quite confused right now.

Comment: Because the Vuetify component is out of reach for the scoped CSS. Are you sure the class/selector is correct? (BTW if `!important` doesn't work you can always override by increasing specificity)

Comment: Is there any other information I could provide to narrow the issue?

Comment: Where did you include the css? In .vue file where the component is, or separate style file? You wrote: `it appeared that my CSS didn't reach the components at all.`, but I don't think we can know why this happens without your file structure and how you import your styles.

Comment: Edited with file structure and vuetify setup.

Comment: Thanks for update. So you are using `<style>
    .v-menu__content {
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>` in `problematicComponent.vue` and it has no effect like it does [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrPvNb)? No other lang but CSS? Even when using `height: 500px !important;`? Are you sure style gets compiled? Perhaps put css somewhere where you are sure it compiles, and see if height changes. I'd encountered problems with watcher when my .vue files wouldn't get compiled after changes for some reason. Try to rebuild and see what happens I guess... AFAICS what you've done has to work.

Comment: I'm using SCSS, would that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once had a similar problem with the vuetify selector component using SCSS. Are you addressing `.v-menu__content` as nested inside `.v-select`? Because, interestingly enough, it isn't a child. It is at the same level as `v-app` (For whatever reason).

Make sure

```
.v-menu__content {
    height: 500px;
}
```

isn't nested inside any other components in your SCSS.

Comment: That's so bizarre! I swear that's the last thing I would have expected to be the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

while writing deep selector write like

```
.any_parent_class(can be any identifier) >>>> target_class{

}
```

i tried it with scoped selector , it worked.
like

```
.flex >>>> .v-menu__content{
}
```

Comment: OP clearly stated that using deep-selectors didn't help.