# Vuetify: color does not apply on UI component

Tags: javascript, css, vuetify.js

In [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/), I used a toolbar component and set its color to `primary`, so it is [supposed](https://lobotuerto.com/thingies/vuetify-color-theme-builder/) to show up in blue, but I see it white:

```
<v-toolbar dark color="primary">
   <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
   </v-btn>
</v-toolbar>
```

Only when I use `<v-toolbar dark>` then I see the toolbar becomes black (as expected), when using `<v-toolbar blue>` (or any other color) it becomes white.

What may be wrong with my settings? I am using the default Vuetify theme (`Vue.use(Vuetify)`).

Comment: Did you wrap it inside [v-app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985784/1981247)?

Comment: Huge kiss @Traxo Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer but it might clarify it a bit.
To style the toolbar you can set the theme just like you already did with:

```
<v-toolbar dark>
```

The `dark` can also be `light`.

To change the color you need to specify it with the color attribute:

```
<v-toolbar color="blue">
```

What you tried to do here won't work. As said the theme can either be `light` or `dark`.

```
<v-toolbar blue>
```

Have you by any change changed the primary color to a white?

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    "primary": "#1976D2",
```

Comment: Default primary is blue anyway afaik, so this cannot be correct? Unless I missed some recent update with that regard?

Comment: I know the default primary is blue but that is why I was wondering if the OP somewhere changed it. If the OP didn't change the primary color there is some other problem or a bug. the `v-app` you mentioned seems like a pretty likely problem. I also know that Vuetify uses quite a lot if `!important` styling https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3400 which might also lead to unexpected behaviour when overwriting styles.

Comment: Good points but setting a color on toolbar is 101, there should not be any problems with that so I'm 99.9% sure it's not wrapped inside `v-app` unless there were recent changes which I'm unaware of. We will see when they check back :) Regardless, I marked it as duplicate because the problem is the same as the linked one.

Comment: In fact I tried that before asking (sorry, I forgot to mention it) but it did not take effect. Thank you for the feedback though