# Vuetify.js: color prop in v-stepper does not take effect when deployed on Gitlab. How to move color prop to a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, css, gitlab, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Using Vuetify.js [`v-stepper`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) component, I can change the color of `v-stepper-step` using the `color` prop:

```
<v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 2" color="red" step="2">Name of step 2</v-stepper-step>
```

This works fine when I am using Vuetify in Nuxt.js and launch the server locally. But I noticed when I deploy my application on Gitlab, the color prop does not take effect and inspecting the element in question simply shows an empty style:

```
element.style {
}
```

That is why I tried to use a class instead:

```
<v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1" class="step-number">Name of step 1</v-stepper-step>
```

Here is that CSS class:

```
.step-number {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

I do this in the hope to action the color prop from within a CSS class and deploy again on Gitlab to see the output, however this does not work even locally.

[image]

How to overcome this issue?

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/begueradj/pen/ePrRNm).

Comment: You must target the proper element: `.v-stepper__step__step {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}`. But wait, I noticed that some styles didn't work for me when I built my large vuetify project for production. So I think this is not specific to the `color` prop. It's been months since I noticed that some of my vuetify css is not working in production build (but works locally), and this is the first post that I've seen that has the similar issue. I asked community, but no response. So I'm not sure what is the real solution for this. (But maybe I'm crazy.)

Comment: Good to hear I am not alone :) I actually [reported](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5354) this as a bug @Traxo

Comment: But just to be clear, it doesn't work when you build it with `npm run build` (or yarn, or whatever is the alternative command for building for the production?)? Have you tried different servers maybe?

Comment: It does not matter whether I use `yarn` or `npm` ... We deploy only on Gitlab  (because it costs)

Answer (score 1):

CSS `color` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) is used to style text. It's different than vue property `color`.

You can use ([demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxqgLg)):

```
.step-number > .v-stepper__step__step{
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: @BillalBegueradj It doesn't work if you are using scoped styles, [here is how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985784/1981247).