# How to remove padding of List item in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When coding Vue project with vuetify, I found there are useless padding in `<v-list>` tag, in detail, it is about `<v-list-tile>` tag.

image: https://segmentfault.com/img/bVbtemC?w=890&h=1288

There are one parent list item and one child list item, and there are some padding space in left and right.

I have followed official methods to set `class="pa-0"`, however, it does not work when I add this class to all the tags around.

And of course set CSS directly does not work too, the image above shows that the target tag is the one with `class="v-list__tile"`, but CSS on this class still does not work.

```
  <v-navigation-drawer width="200px" stateless value="true"
    class="transparent">
    <v-list subheader dense expand>
      <v-list-group no-action>
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-tile class="pa-0">
            <v-icon left>home</v-icon>
            <v-list-tile-title>menu-name-m</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </template>

        <v-list-tile class="pa-0" @click="onMenuCliked">
          <v-list-tile-title>no child - menu-name</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>

      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
```

This is my code partly, it is in vue-cli.

I know remove `no-action` in `<v-list-group>` tag works on child list item, but it is not the way I want, and this does not work on the parent one.

I hope I can control the green padding in the image above, or juest remove it.

Comment: `> but CSS on this class still does not work.`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985783/vuetify-css-not-working-taking-effect-inside-component

Answer (score 2):

`v-list-item` renders the following html

```
<div role="listitem">
  <div class="v-list__tile theme--light">

  </div>
</div>
```

So setting the `class` appends it to the parent div, instead of `v-list__tile` - which is the actually div with the padding.
Sometimes vuetify way around this is using the `content-class` prop instead, but this component does not seem to support it, so you gotta target it by css, for example

```
.v-list__tile {
  padding: 0  
}
```

You could still use class if you want more specificity:

```
<v-list-tile class="my-tile">

.my-tile .v-list__tile {
  padding: 0  
}
```

If it's not working and you are using scoped styles, [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985783/vuetify-css-not-working-taking-effect-inside-component)

Answer (score 1):

V-list is adding only left padding, so you can just simply remove it without setting all paddings to 0.

To remove left padding only you can simply add 'pl-0' class to your v-list-tile.

```
<v-list-tile class="pl-0">
```

[Read more about spacing here.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct, but it works:

```
<v-list-item 
    style="padding-inline-start: 16px !important;"
    :title="item.title"
    :to="item.url"
    :prepend-icon="item.icon"
></v-list-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved a similar problem is to add this in the style:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
::v-deep .v-list-item {
  padding: 0;
}
```