# How to change the size of v-slider?

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, sass, vuetify.js

I try to change the height of the v-slide bar, I have tried with the directive of the component but it only changes the height of the container and I have also tried to overwrite the css with the classes

Any suggestions?

Component: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders#sliders

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while, but here is my answer.

Try this:

```
  >>>.v-slider__thumb {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
  }

  >>>.v-slider--horizontal .v-slider__track-container {
    height: 10px;
  }
```

If you want to learn how this works, read [this](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).
Also I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985784/6132402), there is explained in more detail.

Here is my result:

[image]

**Please** if this was helpful to you, mark this as a correct answer:)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this question has already been answered by the Vuetify support team, I cannot contrast whether your comment is correct because the application version has undergone several changes. Anyway thanks for sharing an answer.

Comment: Great! Maybe it would be helpful if you share what they answered to you. Just to know if this is the best way to modify the components. :) @Victor

Comment: The note won't work with scss or sass. Must be regular CSS to work

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix it with:

```css
.v-slider__track-container {
   height: 10px;
}
.v-slider__track {
   height: 10px;
}
```

The track container needs to be increased to show the larger line and the track needs to be increased to have a larger line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code snippets are reserved for code that will execute, I've converted yours over to just a formatted code block.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to overwrite the styles with `!important`
like this:

```
   .v-slider__track-container{
      height: 10px !important;
    }
```

Comment: still not working, all this style I use within a single component but in my compiled project the class doesnt even appear