# My vuetify CSS does not take effect on my project

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new in vue and vuetify and I read all the documentations in the internet but I still don't know how to inject CSS from vuetify CSS. I have researched some possible solutions, tried to implement what I searched but I realized that the solutions I have found was for Vue 3.9 and below. I am currently using vue 4.0.5 and vue cli 4.0.5. I badly need a solution to this because I am already spending hours looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience in my latest project. Vuetify has some quirks in it that make CSS styling a little different. In general, using `<style scoped>` will not cause any changes with Vuetify, but using the global scoping `<style>` will. For some properties, you'll only notice changes if you use the `!important` tag.

You'll need to make sure you're wrapping everything and using loaders properly to get your CSS working as you intend. Details regarding that are here in detail:
[Vuetify - CSS not working (taking effect) inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985783/vuetify-css-not-working-taking-effect-inside-component)