# Vuetify v-data-table doesn't increase font size

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Vuetify v-data-table doesn't increase font size.

How can I modify the table's content for me to be able to increase the font size of the text because its too small and hard to read.

```
 <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="allCareers"
    :search="search"
    sort-by="calories"
    class="elevation-1 display-2 white--green"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editArticle(item.ARTICLE_NUM)">edit</v-icon>
      <v-icon small @click="deleteSingleArticle(item.ARTICLE_NUM)">delete</v-icon>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

Style

```
<style scoped>
table.v-table thead tr th {
  font-size: 24px;
}
table.v-table tbody tr td {
  font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see that specificity is required to get what you want here. Using the code pen from the Vuetify documentation, these changes work on the `v-data-table`. Keep in mind that Vuetify has some weird CSS workarounds required without using loaders, like needing to use  instead of  or using `!important` tags.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables
(select "Edit in CodePen" to test these)"

```
.v-data-table th {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.v-data-table td {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Details on loaders and CSS details:
[Vuetify - CSS not working (taking effect) inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985783/vuetify-css-not-working-taking-effect-inside-component)